# Laravel cashier subscription per user role

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have a question. my user has 2 roles (creator, sponsor) and i have a `user_profile` to distinguish per user role. is it possible that a user has a different subscription per role? if so, then should I use the Billable trait on the `UserProfile` model?

My `user_profile` looks like this. as you can see for the `user_id=2` there are two records that has both roles. Is it okay to use the `UserProfile` model or use the `User` model since i have to save the payment method per user and not per role. I am open for any suggestions. Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: making two distinct users will save you a lot of troubles. basically not allowing a user to have the two roles at the same time.

Comment: what do you mean by that? @N69S